# Prove that $\sup S=\sup R,$ if $S\subseteq\Bbb{R}$ is bounded from above and $R\subseteq S$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Please, is this correct?**

Let $S$ be a subset of the real numbers bounded from above and let $R\subseteq S$ satisfy the following condition: $\forall\;x\in S,\;\exists\; r\in R\;\text{such that}\;x\leq r$.
I want to prove that \begin{align} \sup S=\sup R.\end{align}

**PROOF**

Let $x\in S$ be arbitrary, then $\exists\; r\in R\;\text{such that}\;x\leq r.$ The number, $r$, is an upper bound for the set $S.$ So, $\sup S\leq r,\;\text{for some} \; r\in R.$ By definition of $\sup,\;\;y\leq\sup R, \forall\; y\in R.$ In particular, $y=r,\;r\leq\sup R.$ Thus,
 \begin{align}\tag{1} \sup S\leq r\leq\sup R.\end{align}
Since $R\subseteq S$, we have
  \begin{align}\tag{2} \sup R\leq \sup S.\end{align}
Thus, \begin{align} \sup S=\sup R.\end{align}

Comment: Your $r$ is not necessarily an upper bound for $S$.

$r$ depends on $x$. So, how do you conclude that $r$ is an upper bound for $S$? Choose, for example, $S = (0,1)$ and $R= S \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @trancelocation: You are indeed, right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you confuse "$\color{blue}{\forall}\;x\in S,\;\color{blue}{\exists}\; r\in R\;\text{such that}\;x\leq r$" with "$\color{blue}{\exists}\; r\in R\; \color{blue}{\forall}\;x\in S,\;\text{such that}\;x\leq r$".

The sets $S = (0,1)$ and $R= S \cap \mathbb{Q}$ satisfy the condition: $\color{blue}{\forall}\;x\in S,\;\color{blue}{\exists}\; r\in R\;\text{such that}\;x\leq r$. 
But your conclusion $\sup S \leq r$ is not true for any $r \in R$.

To show that $\sup R = \sup S$ you may proceed as follows:

- Show $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists x_{\epsilon}\in R: \sup S - \epsilon < x_{\epsilon}$
  $$\Rightarrow \forall \epsilon >0: \sup S - \epsilon < \sup R \Rightarrow \sup S \leq \sup R$$
  That's exactly what was to be shown.

Comment: (+1) You claimed that "But your conclusion $\sup S\leq r$ is not true for any $r\in R$"but I claimed  $\sup S\leq r$ for some $r\in R$" instead.

Comment: @OmojolaMicheal: If it is not true for any $r$ in the given case, then there is also no specific $r$, for which it is suddenly true.

Comment: I get you now. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\sup R<\sup S$. Then $\sup R$ is not an upper bound of $S$, thus $\exists x\in S|\sup R<x\le\sup S$. But this is a contradiction, since $\forall r\in R, r\le\sup R<x$, and it implies there does not exist any $r\ge x$. This means $\sup R=\sup S$.